# Cleaning up transaction replication del/ins/upd stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, sql-server-2000, transactional-replication

I'm referring to the ones that start with:

dbo.sp_MSdel...
dbo.sp_MSins...
dbo.sp_MSupd...

I've noticed they are not removed when I run `exec sp_dropsubscription` on the Publisher then run `sp_removedbreplication` on the subscriber (on the database).  I also tried `sp_subscription_cleanup` to no avail.

Do these have to be deleted manually if I want them removed?

Subscriber is SQL 2000
Publisher is SQL 2008 (Distribution database is on the Publisher)

Answer (score 1):

When you remove a subscription nothing is done to the subscriber.  You'll need to remove these procedures manually.  They are safe to remove is replication has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with SQL 2000 replication, the replication bits does not get cleaned up easily. You can follow [this method](https://repltalk.com/2010/11/17/how-to-cleanup-replication-bits/) for cleaning up the left over bits.

As Denny mentioned, they are safe to remove as the replication is already removed.